# javascript http get operation issue

Tags: javascript, http

I am new to Javascript and try to find a solution to my issue but failed. My problem is, I have an input text box and a search submit button, and when user clicks the Search submit button, I want to redirect user to url `http://testsearch/results.aspx?k=<value of text box k>`, for example, if user put "StackOverflow" into text box and then clicks the search button, I want to redirect user to the following page, any solutions?

http://testsearch/results.aspx?k=StackOverflow

```
  <input type="text" id="k" name="k" />
  <input type="submit" id="Go" value="Search" />
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" id="Go" value="Search" onclick="location.href = 'http://testsearch/results.aspx?k='+document.getElementById('k').value;" />
```

Note that it's a `button`, not a `submit`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need javascript for this, just change the form method from POST to GET:

```
<form method=GET action="http://testsearch/results.aspx">
```

The "?k=StackOverflow" will magically be appended. It's what form method GET does.

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't require javascript, just a simple html form.

```
<form method="get" action="http://testsearch/results.aspx">
<input type="text" id="k" name="k" />
<input type="submit" id="Go" value="Search" /> 
</form>
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Unfortunately it won't work because it seems this is an ASP.NET application where you can have only a single form per page, the method is set to `POST` and you don't have much control over the action. I suppose the original poster should have tagged this question with `asp.net`.

Comment: ASP.NET cannot possibly be so bad that you can't turn off the "The entire page is a single form" feature, can it? If you really need to use JavaScript to get a form this simple to work, then your underlying system is hidiously broken and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Even if the ASP.NET helpers for forms are so limited, surely it's still possible to have the code dump some raw HTML into the output?

Comment: @James ASP.NET has a tenancy to wrap the entire content of the `body` in a form - and you can't nest forms.

Comment: I've avoided ASP.NET, so what I know of it comes mostly from seeing what problems other people are having with it, but I get the impression that it is very much designed to allow Windows application developers to build websites without understanding how websites work, and (as a consequence) makes it very hard to approach development from the "web" end instead of the ".NET" end. I gather that ASP.NET MVC doesn't have this issue & could be a reasonable environment for web work (I'm still avoiding it on the principle that I don't want to get to grips with Windows as a server and dev platform).

Answer (score 1):

Use

**[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location)**

to go to the new location.

To get the textbox value you can use

```
document.getElementById ( "k" ).value;
```

and the whole code will be

```
var textValue = document.getElementById ( "k" ).value;

window.location = 'http://testsearch/results.aspx?k=' + textValue;
```

Comment: If you would use this way, you should urlencode the value
var textValue = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById ( "k" ).value);
but, for this case, you should rather use <form> element.